# Replacing missing wind speed data from a nearby site

Tags: time-series, missing-data, interpolation

I am doing a project that is looking at testing various imputation methods for estimating missing wind speed at a site in Trinidad. The dataset consist of hourly wind speeds for 15 years. I have tried simple methods like listwise deletion, mean substitution, linear regression, cublic & linear interpolation, nearest neighbor and even Markov chain monte carlo multiple imputation. Are there any other methods that could accurately estimate the wind speeds? I would also like to know if it is possible to use the respective Known wind speed data from a nearby site like in Tobago to replace the specific missing points in Trinidad?

Comment: This type of imputation might be reasonable if the wind speed in nearby areas are highly positively correlated with the wind speed at the missing location,

Comment: when i tested the correlation between the two sites, I got a value of 0.635.